# Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, mstest

Is there anything special that the "Unit Test Project" project template in Visual Studio does in addition to a regular class library? Since MSTest also runs tests in a class library, is there any difference between using these two?

Comment: Almost the same, except the unit test template adds MSTest references and also include some skeleton code.

Comment: You also get a few test related menu items in the right-click menu of a Unit Test Project. The "add" menu item will have test related items your class library won't have.